# SQL Server - aggregate the data

Tags: sql, sql-server

The below is the data I have. How to aggregate the data based on ID and Room but if the room is repeating it should not aggregate to the first appearance?

It should be aggregated like the below result set.

Data set:

```
ID      Room    Length  AD
-----------------------------------
1001    MM        2     2018-06-26
1001    MM        3     2018-06-26
1001    MM        0.5   2018-06-26
1001    MM        3     2018-06-28
1001    A5        3.5   2018-06-29
1001    MM        4.4   2018-06-29
1001    MM        3.2   2018-06-30
1001    A5        2.1   2018-07-02
1001    A5        1.7   2018-07-03
```

Expected result:

```
ID     Room   Sum_Length
-----------------------
1001    MM      8.5
1001    A5      3.5
1001    MM      7.6
1001    A5      3.8
```

Comment: I do not understand grouping for MM, you group by ID, Room and AD? What does it consist of 8.5? @user10260125

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems you need differences of `row_number()` :

```
select id, room, sum(Length)
from (select t.*, row_number() over (partition by id order by ad) seq1,
                  row_number() over (partition by id, room order by ad) seq2
      from table t
     ) t
group by id, room, (seq1 - seq2);
```

Comment: Thanks, Yogesh, I also need it to be in order like below.
ID  Room    Sum_Length, rank
1001    MM  8.5     1
1001    A5  3.5       2
1001    MM  7.6      3
1001    A5  3.8         4

Comment: I got it. Thanks, Yogesh. it's really helpful.